# Не понимаю почему после 2 уровня кейборд кнопок не работают хэндлеры

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, handlers

Так вот, если нажать на кнопку Astra (это уже второй уровень меню), то ничего не происходит, есть подозрение что это у aiogram ограничение на количество уровней кб кнопок. так вот может быть кто ни будь знает что делать?

```
from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove
import os

bot = Bot('xxx')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def on_startup(_):
    print('Все работает')

#######################################HANDLERS########################################
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def command_start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Автор бота: @uzjakoweban')
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет!, это бот который поможет тебе при игре в Valorant!')
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что бы начать нажми: /Button', reply_markup=button)
    await message.delete()

    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['Button'])
async def command_second_start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери карту на которой играешь)' ,reply_markup=kb_button)
    await message.delete()



#####################################KEYBOARD_HANDLERS#################################
###1УРОВЕНЬ###
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def first_menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Split':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Split', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Heaven':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Heaven', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Bind':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Bind', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Accent':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Accent', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Fracture':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Fracture', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Breeze':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Breeze', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Icebox':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Icebox', reply_markup=kb_button2)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Вернуться в главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Автор бота: @uzjakoweban', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет!, это бот который поможет тебе при игре в Valorant!')
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что бы начать нажми: /Button')
        await message.delete()



###2УРОВЕНЬ###
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def second_menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Astra':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Astra', reply_markup=kb_button)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Breach':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Breach', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Brimstone':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Brimstone', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Chamber':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Chamber', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Cypher':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Cypher', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Fade':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Fade', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Jett':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Jett', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'KAY/O':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой KAY/O', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Killjoy':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Killjoy', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Neon':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Neon', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Omen':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Omen', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Phoenix':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Phoenix', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Raze':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Raze', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Sage':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Sage', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Skye':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Skye', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Sova':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Sova', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Viper':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Viper', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Yoru':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Yoru', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Вернуться в главное меню':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Автор бота: @uzjakoweban', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет!, это бот который поможет тебе при игре в Valorant!')
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что бы начать нажми: /Button')
        await message.delete()

###3УРОВЕНЬ###
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def third_menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'A spot':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана точка А')
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери сторону')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'B spot':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана точка B')
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери сторону')
        await message.delete()


####################################KB_BUTTONS##########################################
# a1 = KeyboardButton('/Button')

# button = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
# button.add(a1)

###1УРОВЕНЬ###
a1 = KeyboardButton('Split')
a2 = KeyboardButton('Heaven')
a3 = KeyboardButton('Bind')
a4 = KeyboardButton('Accent')
a5 = KeyboardButton('Fracture')
a6 = KeyboardButton('Breeze')
a7 = KeyboardButton('Icebox')
a8 = KeyboardButton('Вернуться в главное меню')

kb_button = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
kb_button.insert(a1).insert(a2).insert(a3).insert(a4).insert(a5).insert(a6).insert(a7).add(a8)

###2УРОВЕНЬ###
b1 = KeyboardButton('Astra')
b2 = KeyboardButton('Breach')
b3 = KeyboardButton('Brimstone')
b4 = KeyboardButton('Chamber')
b5 = KeyboardButton('Cypher')
b6 = KeyboardButton('Fade')
b7 = KeyboardButton('Jett')
b8 = KeyboardButton('KAY/O')
b9 = KeyboardButton('Killjoy')
b10 = KeyboardButton('Neon')
b11 = KeyboardButton('Omen')
b12 = KeyboardButton('Phoenix')
b13 = KeyboardButton('Raze')
b14 = KeyboardButton('Reyna')
b15 = KeyboardButton('Sage')
b16 = KeyboardButton('Skye')
b17 = KeyboardButton('Sova')
b18 = KeyboardButton('Viper')
b19 = KeyboardButton('Yoru')
b20 = KeyboardButton('Вернуться в главное меню')


kb_button2 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
kb_button2.row(b1, b2, b3, b4, b5).row(b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, ).row(b11, b12, b13, b14, b15).row(b16, b17, b18, b19).insert(b20)

###3УРОВЕНЬ###
c1 = KeyboardButton('A spot')
c2 = KeyboardButton('B spot')

kb_button3 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
kb_button3.add(c1).add(c2)

###4УРОВЕНЬ###

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таких ограничений в телеграме нет - это раз. Второе вы плохо понимаете работу хендлеров в боте.
Штош. Смотрите, когда юзер присылает сообщение боту оно проходит по, скажем так, списку хендлеров, и по фильтрам в этих самых хендлерах. Если фильтр говорит False то он игнорируется и идет проверка фильтра след хендлера. Когда же фильтр вернет True то перебор хендлеров остановиться и сработает код из этого хендлера.
Вернемся к вам. Итак, я не зная заметили ли вы, но у вас два хендлера с одинаковыми фильтрами `content_types='text'`(который к слову можно не писать, он стоит по умолчанию). Итак вопрос, что же произойдет если юзер вам что-то отправит? Верно, сработает первый хендлер, фильтр которого вернет True, так как, ну, вы же текст отправили? Вот такие дела.
Ладно. Как фиксить?
Вариант 1 - это юзать FSM.

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

class FSMKbLevels(StatesGroup):
    level_1 = State()
    level_2 = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup().add(...)
    await message.answer("отправляю клаву 1 лвла", reply_markup=markup)
    # там где вы отправляете первую клаву запустите состояние как показано ниже
    await FSMKbLevels.level_1.set()

# потом вот тут добавляем фильтр на state
# этот хендлер принимает текст но только если состояние у юзера FSMKbLevels.level_1
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMKbLevels.level_1)
async def first_menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Split':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Split', reply_markup=kb_button2)
    if message.text == 'Heaven':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Heaven', reply_markup=kb_button2)
    ...
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери героя')
    # тут уже объявляем второй state
    await FSMKbLevels.level_2.set()
    await message.delete()

# по аналогии с первым хендлером, но другим стейтом
@dp.message_handler(state=FSMKbLevels.level_2)
async def second_menu(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Astra':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбрана карта Astra', reply_markup=kb_button)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()

    if message.text == 'Breach':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбран герой Breach', reply_markup=kb_button3)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери точку')
        await message.delete()
```

Ну и остальное по тому же алгоритму.
Второй вариант - это поменять ReplyKeyboard на инлайн кнопки, очень рекомендую их изучить, там можно обойтись без стейтов.
Расписывать его не буду так как лень. =) Удачи

Comment: Господи, святой вы человек! Спасибо вам)